# C# Webbrowser control keydown not firing

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a System.Windows.Forms webbrowser control that is not firing the keydown events.

Here is the code: the mouse down event fires, but the keydown event does not. Are there any criteria for the keydown event triggering?

```
IWebBrowser2 browser;
        mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;

        browser = (IWebBrowser2)_browser.ActiveXInstance;

        if (browser == null)
            return;

        doc = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document;

        if (doc == null)
            return;

        iEvent = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;

        if (iEvent != null)
        {
            iEvent.onkeydown += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onkeydownEventHandler(keyDown);
            iEvent.onmousedown += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onmousedownEventHandler(iEvent_onmousedown);
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling key events on WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649441/handling-key-events-on-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Thanks - it does look like this is a duplicate...In that case, is there any way to bubble that event up to my mainform where I handle other keypress events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown`. Since `PreviewKeyDown` fires before `KeyDown` event.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) for more information on how to bind this event.

Hope this helps