# Resize on the key firing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a classic Form1 class that inherits the Form class. 
The problem is I press the buttons and no events get fired.
Inside the Form1 there is a webBrowser which occupies the whole Form1.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        KeyPreview = true;
        PreviewKeyDown += wb_PreviewKeyDown; 
    }

     private void wb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EDOOOOOOOOO");   
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            // Do something funny!
        }
    }
}
```

The wb_PreviewKeyDown is not fired whatever button I push.

Comment: Use button click event not form keydown

Comment: That code works as expected provided that you have it inside a Form derived class and you call the Show/ShowDialog methods

Comment: Of course, KeyDown event is for the Keyboard not for the button

Comment: Are you sure you `Form1` has the focus when you press the keyboard?

Comment: You should have mentioned earlier that you are using a `WebBrowser` on that form. In that case  `Form1` will never get the keydown because the `WebBrowser` will eat any messages.

Comment: Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649441/handling-key-events-on-webbrowser-control) can help

Comment: I also edited my answer for this

Answer (score 0):

If you press a key on the form, the event will get fired.
However, if you have a TextBox or something on the form, and you press a key on that, the event will NOT fire, because now the TextBox has received the input.

This can easily be fixed by setting the property `KeyPreview = true` on the form.
You can set this in the designer, or in code (see the answer of @Isma)

**EDIT:** 
Since you have a `WebBrowser` control on your form, you need to do it somewhat different, see this [Handling key events on WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649441/handling-key-events-on-webbrowser-control)

It involves using the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the `WebBrowser`

Comment: This is working on my side, if this does not works for you then there must be some other code that breaks this. Can you provide us with a minimal code example ?

Comment: The events are not fired again :/ .

Comment: Have you altered your code ? In that case update your question and show us your new code

Comment: I found the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252444/handle-tab-key-press-on-webbrowser-control-and-prevent-switching-between-html-el  where can I write it ? in the question ?

Comment: You may answer your own question, so it can help others with the same problem